# Reactjs webbrowser application not able to view on mobile/Ipad browser safari or chrome.Able to view on desktop and on dev tools for any device

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Have deployed the site in heroku and here's the URL:https://mo-betta.herokuapp.com/login.

All other browsers on mobile/Ipad are returning empty blank page.
The code repo can be found in https://github.com/bssheetal/Mo-Betta

Mainly using bootstrap,React js for front end.Please let me know ur thoughts why im not able to view on different browsers

**This is the only console errors I see:**
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico (Resource size is not correct - typo in the Manifest?)

**Warnings:**

1/src/components/Chat/RoomList.js
  Line 19:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid

2../src/components/NewsList/index.js
  Line 20:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank

Comment: Hi! please elaborate your problem. If you can see an error in the console please provide it. You should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added more info